# Should I use Google Volley instead of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I did some research on Google `Volley` and found that it is somewhat easy and clean to use.

But I am still not sure as to what the advantages of using it are and whether I should still use the `AsyncTask`.

I know `AsyncTask` works as a `background task` and that it is separate but what about `Volley`?

Which one should I opt for?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-vs-asynctask-better-approach/.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly an opinion based question that is largely dependent on the needs of your particular application.  Volley provides a lot of things for you out of the box, like network caching (assuming you're given correct cache headers from your server), and an easy to use API with all of your callbacks and different threading layers handled for you.  So, it really depends on what you're looking.  Personally, I think any production worthy application should use some sort of networking library that a team has spent plenty of time patching and prepping for you (rather than trying to reinvent the wheel), and since a Google team has gone through the trouble for doing this for you...why not?

Answer (score 2):

One cannot compare Volley with an AsyncTask.

So your question makes no sense.